# Tomcat not working in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

I start my tomcat server in eclipse and I get an error that says

Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor. Pls help. 
I tried changing the server timeout but it doesn't work

Comment: what are the values you given for timeouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse editor go to the `Servers view tab --> Double click on Tomcat Server`, 
Then you are able to see the Tomcat Overview page, in that go to 
`Timeouts tab --> click on the tab --> increase the start and stop time`.

**For Example:**
start(in seconds):  1000
stop (in seconds):  100

Comment: tnx but it only worked after creating a new server and changing the timeouts